# Não consigo retornar ID ao inserir dados pelo POST do Controller ASP NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-web-api, post

Tenho o código abaixo, e preciso que o ID seja retornado assim que eu inserir o objeto. Caso já exista projeto cadastrado, ele não faz a inserção, mas preciso que me retorne algum dado como vazio ou nulo, porém não consigo definir uma mesma variável para guardar um valor nulo e um valor vindo de projeto por terem tipos diferentes, então o que devo fazer neste caso?

```
        public ActionResult<Project> Post(Project project)
        {
            var get = _acess.GetProject(project.Id);

            try
            {


                if (get == null)
                {
                    _acess.AddProject(project);
                }
                else
                {
                    get = null;
                }

                return Ok();
            }
            catch (DataException ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para garantir que sua webApi esteja mais aderente às boas práticas de uma aplicação RESTful, é importante que você retorne o statuscode **201** quando o item for **criado** e **200** quando **não houver erro e nem necessidade de criar** o projeto.

Veja abaixo como fica:

```cs
public ActionResult<Project> Post(Project project)
{
    var get = _acess.GetProject(project.Id);

    try
    {
        if (get == null)
        {
            _acess.AddProject(project);
            var urlDoNovoProjeto = $"api/projetos/{project.Id}";
            return Created(urlDoNovoProjeto, project);
        }
        else
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Você deve substituir o valor da variável `urlDoNovoProjeto` conforme sua rota.

Comment: Consegui, muitíssimo obrigado!